# Remove the unwanted zf2 modules

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

How can i remove the zend framework 2 module, i first install the zfcuser module mistakenly.

I install using the command:

```
php composer.phar require zf-commons/zfc-user:0.1.*
```

Now want to remove it via composer, how to achieve that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `remove` command:

```
$ composer remove zf-commons/zfc-user
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used the php composer.phar update in the command prompt, after removing the module line in the composer.json file, that does the same.